# What are possible causes for an HTML element to be hidden?

Tags: html, css

I have a div that is visible, block display, has a height and width, is position:fixed to be in (100,100), and has a z-index higher than everything else on the page.

What possibly could be causing me not to see this div? I can't post the code itself, sadly, but doesn't this cover pretty much everything in HTML/CSS that could be causing it not to be displayed?

[image]

Comment: Click *Inspect element* at position 100, 100. What element do you see? Can you add a picture of your page (optionally, replaced everything with dummy content/colours)?

Comment: Same on all browsers?  Is there a parent element (and what are its properties)?  Is there content inside the div - sometimes that influences things.

Comment: @RobW - browser is Chrome (haven't tested on other browsers). The question is general ... right now it does't reproduce. If I can reproduce, I'll post more details.

Comment: Select the HTML element in Firebug. This will at least show you if and where the element is being rendered. I'm guessing the fixed position is the cause, but without seeing the surrounding HTML and CSS it's very difficult to say.

Comment: @MrLister - this sounds like a possible answer. Is there a way to see the inherited style? Anyway, post it as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: @ripper234: Scroll down the inspector.

Comment: OK, I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than the properties you mention, there is also `visibility` and `opacity`. Your screendump doesn't show inherited styles, so you could check if those are inherited. Also look at any inherited `!important` styles.

In addition, the `z-index` only works correctly if both the element and the parent are positioned. So that could mean the `z-index` is ignored here and the div could be obscured by other elements following it later.

Answer (score 0):

This is one possibility:

```
opacity: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be something wrong with the browser interpretation, try viewing in a different browser.